# What happened with Ubtao?

Tags: forgotten-realms, lore, religions-and-deities

What happened with Chult and Ubtao during 4e? Ubtao's gone, and Dendar the Night Serpent was released and became a god. How and why did those events transpire?

Comment: Are you asking about what happened during the 4e, or how things changed in 5e following what happened during the 4e?

Comment: Both, i think :)  Main thing i want to know- why and how Ubtao has gone, and Dendar was released.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 4e *FR Campaign Guide* is completely silent about the topics you raise. Neither Dendar, nor Ubtao appear in its index. To the extent that I could track, Dendar is mentioned only one time in name as a primordial, and one more time as simply the Night Serpent while the Shadow Epoch (before -35000DR) is discussed. The Shadow Epoch is also the only time we hear about Ubtao the Deceiver, as the traitor who sided with the elder gods against fellow primordials. 4e *FR Player's Guide* has nothing at all regarding these topics; I could not identify a single instance where their names appear at all.

The main things we know from these two 4e books is that Chult became a separate island of its own after the Spellplague and the merging of Abeir and Toril. Mezro turned into a pit that was being haunted by various undead.

The 5e *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* is also thin in terms of information regarding Chult. Sadly the Second Sundering has not restored Mezro, it is still described as a ruined city haunted by the undead. Ubtao is not mentioned in the book (does not appear in the index), and Dendar is only mentioned as one of the possible warlock patrons; and is described to be from the Far Realm of the Great Old Ones.

In short, I don't believe there are RAW answers to your question(s) in the campaign settings. Dendar does not appear to have been released though, and it has not become a deity.

Finally, according to the recent 5e adventure *Tomb of Annihilation*, (spoilers ahead):

> 9 primal spirits came to be worshipped as gods after Ubtao's departure, but they were then destroyed by Greyhawk's infamous demilich Acererak, so it is unclear how much the FR designers want to continue the Ubtao-Dendar story for the future of Chult. However we also read that Ubtao left because of strife amongst his followers and their over-reliance on him, that yuanti are planning to open a portal to free the Night Serpent, and that Mezro planeshifted, so there may be more to come.

Comment: @MaxKrilov The introduction chapter of ToA has a sidebar titled "Gods of Chult" that gives a quick rundown on why Ubtao departed, plus a little extra info in another section in Chapter 3 describing the history of a city.

Answer (score 6):

To add to [ZwiQ's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108318/what-happened-with-ubtao/108334#108334):

The DMs Guild Adept "Lost City of Mezro" line of supplements provide, not the full story, but tantalizing details about the Fate of Ubtao as well as the fates of Mezro and Artus Cimber. Mainly ["Ruins of Mezro"](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/220852/Ruins-of-Mezro) and ["Maze of Shadows"](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/251151/Maze-of-Shadows) to be specific.

Then there are AL adventures that cover the release of Dendar the Night Serpent, and presumably how the end of the world is averted. I haven't read them myself but they are (in order):

- [Streams of Crimson](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/238650/DDAL0715-Streams-of-Crimson)
- [Pools of Cerulean](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/238651/DDAL0716-Pools-of-Cerulean)
- [Cauldrons of Sapphire](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/241653/DDAL0717-Cauldrons-of-Sapphire)
- [Turn Back the Endless Night](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/241654/DDAL0718-Turn-Back-the-Endless-Night)

Finally, the Power Guide's [Tomb of Annihilation Companion](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/225854/Tomb-of-Annihilation-Companion) suggests powers for the four legendary treasures described (but not statted up) by the hardcover adventure. Let's just say it would be bad news if one out of the four fell in Dendar's hands, as the old snake battles its way out of the underworld. :-)

---

PS. Do note that none of this is official first-party material, so I'm making no pretense of giving a RAW answer here. Consider this to be "helpful cruft" for those wanting more than what the previous answer can give. It's badly scattered, but if taken together, I would say it does hint at a "semi-offical" answer to the question asked, and related issues.